# Change JScrollBar arrow height

Tags: java, swing

How do you change the height of the arrows in JScroll Bar? I was able to change the width of
the Scrollbar but the height of arrows were still small. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Painting is done by a couple of BasicArrowButtons, which have this in their paint method:

```
// Draw the arrow
size = Math.min((h - 4) / 3, (w - 4) / 3);
size = Math.max(size, 2);
paintTriangle(g, (w - size) / 2, (h - size) / 2,
                    size, direction, isEnabled);
```

So need to create a class which paints the arrows differently, then a ScrollBarUI that adds these arrows to your JScrollBar, then set that on your JScrollBar.